# I want to store a character array, clear screen and then make the char array display again

Tags: c++, arrays, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

char map[10][20] = {
    "###################",
    "#@                #",
    "#                 #",
    "#                 #",
    "#                 #",
    "#                 #",
    "#                 #",
    "#                 #",
    "#                 #",
    "###################"
};

int x = 1;
int y = 1;

bool game_running = true;

int main()
{
    while(game_running == true){
        system("cls");
        for(int display=0; display<10; display++){
            cout << map[display] << endl;
        }

        system("pause>nul");

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)){
            int y2 = y + 1;
            if(map[y2][x] == ' '){
                map[y][x] = ' ';
                y++;
                map[y][x] = '@';
            }
        }
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)){
            int y2 = y - 1;
            if(map[y2][x] == ' '){
                map[y][x] = ' ';
                y = y - 1;
                map[y][x] = '@';
            }
        }
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)){
            int x2 = x+1;
            if(map[y][x2] == ' '){
                map [y][x] = ' ';
                x++;
                map[y][x] = '@';
            }
        }
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)){
            int x2 = x-1;
            if(map[y][x2] == ' '){
                map [y][x] = ' ';
                x--;
                map[y][x] = '@';
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code. You can make the @ move by using the arrow keys. I want to be able to clear the screen, do some text stuff and then have the screen come back with the @ sign exactly where it was. How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? What worked/didn't work? SO people don't generally just throw around a bunch of code without some work being done on the asker's part first.

Comment: Because I have no idea what I could try in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to Use a

```
sysytem("cls");
```

this will make it soo the screen clears every second

Comment: It has that already, I am asking how to store a character map and then return it after I clear the screen.